# sending confirmation mail in android

Tags: android, hyperlink

I want to check whether the email provided by user is valid or not. So how do I send confirmation link to his id? I have the code for sending email but I want how to send a link which when clicked will open a webpage.

```
String verify= "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" +"click this "+"</a>";

final sending m = new sending("adsadw@gmail.com", "password"); 
final Context con=this;
String[] toArr = {email}; 
m.setTo(toArr); 
m.setFrom("007sanketh@gmail.com"); 
m.setSubject("Confirmation Link"); 
m.setBody("Please click on this " + verify + "to activate");
//  Log.v("sanketh","here");
Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try { 
            //  m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 
            boolean a=m.send();
            if(a) {
                Toast.makeText(con, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
                Toast.makeText(con, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
        }
    }
});
t1.start();
```

This is the code I tried. Mail works properly but I want to send a link as a confirmation link. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To linkify links in a string you can use this:

```
   String msg = "click here: email@example.com"
   final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg);
   Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
```

You can find a good read on it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html).

Comment: can u just help me on how do i recognize whether the user has clicked on tht link or not,for eg if the link which i provided is wwww.google.com then how ll i come to know tht he has clicked it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you and please accept it as the correct answer. I am not sure about the other question. You should post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String confirmation_mail_link = "www.yoursitename.com"
String mail_body = "<a href=\"" + confirmation_mail_link + "\">" + Click + "</a>"

confirmation_mail_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(mail_body));
```

So it will convert that text 'Click' to a link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx,but well in my mail  method,m not using intent so this doesnot hold any good for me,do u have any other idea?